# Using "absolute" css path in :not pseudo class

Tags: html, css

When I put an "absolute" CSS path in a `:not` pseudo selector, the CSS rule gets ignored in practically every browser except Safari. Is this expected behavior? How can I target this specific element without adding classes or ids?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>This one shouldn't be red</h1>
  </header>
  <h1>This one should be red</h1>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
h1:not(body > header > h1) {
  color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2a3mzn68/1/

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: It works just fine in Safari, I just can't seem to find out why though..

Comment: @RijkvanZanten Because [Safari is the new IE](http://nolanlawson.com/2015/06/30/safari-is-the-new-ie/).

Comment: Have you tried adding a class to the H1 in the header? The Logic in the brackets seems to be breaking this in other browsers but I added a class of header to the H1 in the header and used the CSS selector 
h1:not(.header) {
    color: red;
}
which seems to work

Comment: Safari has better support of CSS Selectors Level 4. Maybe this is the case.

Comment: In CSS3, `:not` only accepts a simple selector. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn

Comment: Why not just do this: `body > h1 {color: red;}`

Comment: ralph.m, you are very right in this particular case, but I came across this problem in a much more complicated situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the most current versions of Chrome (46.0.2490.80), Firefox (41.0.2), Opera (32.0) and Safari (9.0.1), only Safari supports the CSS4 Negation pseudo-class. (According to the browser CSS-Selector at [CSS4-selectors.com](http://css4-selectors.com/browser-selector-test/))

In CSS3 was only a single simple selector allowed as argument for :not.